# Material design listview on Android 4

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design

Hi I'm trying to create listview on Android 4+ similar to those available in material design, something like this https://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4 but with some modifications, after click on item I would like to expand this item in a pretty way scrolling to almost top of the list and making rest of items darken. What is the best way to achieve something like this on Android 4? I was trying to use ExpandableListView but it looks really awfull. Or maybe there is some library which can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use [Transition API](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html) for building animations like this. Most part of this API could be used in android 4+ bu using, for example, this [library](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere)

Comment: I tried to use this library but when I used `getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(transition);` appears problem with using this functionality to achieve this animation. Any other idea to get this animation on Android 4?

Comment: @falsetto it would not work on Android 4. You could make same looking animation by animating different fragments inside one Activity.